# Symfony3 - redirect 301 https -> http -> https

Tags: symfony, redirect

i have problem with redirect 301 in symfony.

my routing.yml

```
homepage-301:
    path: /old-homepage
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /homepage
        permanent: true
```

trace:
[image]

Why is redirect to schema HTTP?

But I want:

https://www.exmaple/old-homepage
https://www.example/homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
homepage-301:
    path: /old-homepage
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /homepage
        permanent: true
    schemes:  [https]
```